# Can someone deciper this error message for me?

Tags: arch-linux, samba, konsole, error-logging, dolphin-file-manager

Can someone decipher this error message for me?  It reads like it was written in one language, translated into another using google-translate, done a second time, done a third time (except this time using another service instead of google-translate), and finally translated back into the original english it was written in.  I felt like I was playing the game "Telephone" when I encountered it on the KaOS live USB I'm currently testing and I really would like to know what it's trying to tell me.

In fact, with all the engrish and the punctuation all messed up, this really feels nostalgic and reminds me of, ["This guy are sick."](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/7Hc2cizaLCE/maxresdefault.jpg)

Here's the message:

> ```
> [live@localhost ~]$ dolphin /home/live/.config
> Cannot creat accessible child interface for object:  PlacesView(0x18bcdc0)  index:  19
> We got some errors while running testparm "Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf\nError loading services.\n"
> KSambaShare: Could not find smb.conf!
> We got some errors while running 'net usershare info'
> "Can't load /etc/samba/smb.conf - run testparm to debug it\n"
> ```

Please note, that after viewing that crypic message which scholars will undoubtedly ponder over for eons, the application (dolphin in this case) loaded without any problems and the command functioned perfectly.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This isn’t a comedy site.

Answer (score 0):

It's just telling you that you have no configuration file for [samba](https://www.samba.org/samba/), a tool that allows you to share files and printers with machines running other operating systems such as Windows.

Comment: Is there a package that when launched that would automatically set up the conf for me?  Or should I remove samba and reinstall it to get the configuration set up properly?

Comment: You can probably copy `/etc/samba/smb.conf.example` to `/etc/samba/smb.conf` and edit it as needed.